# Install multiple npm packages from private gitlab registry

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

I'm using gitlab to host my private npm packages. At the moment I've 2 projects I published to the gitlab package registry. Both packages are used by another project (let's say 3rd project). According to the gitlab documentation, I installed both packages in the 3rd project using the following commands:

```
npm config set @myscope:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<first-project-id>/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<first-project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken" "<auth-token>"
npm install @myscope/first-package

npm config set @myscope:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<second-project-id>/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<second-project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken" "<auth-token>"
npm install @myscope/second-package
```

My problem is now that I cannot run a simple "npm install" anymore because my 3rd project depends on the 2 private packages. Sure, I can call "npm config set" before running "npm install" in the 3rd project, but the problem is that when I call "npm config set" for the second project, it replaces the first config (because both are having the same scope). So I can only install 1 package, for the second I'm getting an error because it cannot be found (because it has another project-id in gitlab, thus another package registry url). I already tried the following without success:

```
npm config set @myscope/first-package:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<first-project-id>/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<first-project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken" "<auth-token>"
npm install @myscope/first-package

npm config set @myscope/second-package:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<second-project-id>/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<second-project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken" "<auth-token>"
npm install @myscope/second-package
```

But now I cannot install any of the packages. So, anyone know how I can set the registry-url for packages sharing the same scope but having a different url?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by using the instance-level installation. First, I thought it's not working for me because it still told me 404. But the problem was that gitlab instructs me to run `npm config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken' "<my-token>"`. But this is not working on my Windows because of the apostrophes that surrounds the url. I replaced them with " and now everything works fine.

Comment: I have simmilar problem. I try to add two npm libraries to my project, which are stored in gitlab package registry, but npm is looking for them in npmjs.org, but not in my gitlab. Even after I add both libraries with doudle quotes npm still overwrites line with authToken. Also windows machine.

Comment: Actually, npm doesn't overwrites authToken, but I can do npm install only for last added library. For the first one node is looking at npmjs.org