# Using two or more npm libraries from gitlab npm package in Angular project

Tags: npm, gitlab

I have two npm libraries, stored in our company's gitlab package repository. Both libraries are separate gitlab projects with different ids.
If i try to use them separately - everything is fine. But I can't use them both in, let's say, third project.

I found only one solution for similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455550/install-multiple-npm-packages-from-private-gitlab-registry), but it didn't helped me.

My steps:

STEP 1

```
npm config set @my-reg/library-one-project-name:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN"

npm config set @my-reg/library-two-project-name:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN"
```

NPM registry file:

```
@my-reg/library-one-project-name:registry=https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN
@my-reg/library-two-project-name:registry=https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN
```

RESULT 1: npm tries to donwload packages from npmjs.org

---

STEP 2

```
npm config set @my-reg:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN"

npm config set @my-reg:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN"
```

NPM registry file:

```
https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/=
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN
https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/=
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN
```

RESULT 2: npm tries to donwload packages from npmjs.org

---

STEP 3

```
npm config set @my-scope:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN"

npm config set @my-scope:registry https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken" "PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN"
```

NPM registry file:

```
@my-scope:registry=https://gitlab.asseco.lt/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/111111/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_ONE_TOKEN
//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/projects/222222/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECT_TWO_TOKEN
```

RESULT 3: npm downloads SECOND library from gitlab, but tries to donwload first package from npmjs.org

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create token for the projects group in gitlab (not for single npm project), where libraries are stored and add this key to npm config for all packages from this registry. Here is how you can add multiple libraries from the same scope to project:

```
npm config set @my-scope:registry=https://gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/packages/npm/
npm config set "//gitlab.some.url/gitlab/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=PROJECTS_GROUP_TOKEN"
```